# infinite draggable element with jquery ui draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create an element that grows and shrink while dragging.
This works by dragging up and to the right. Only it doesn't work by dragging to the left and bottom.

For more details please see the code snippet.

```js
    var move = {
        drag: function () {
            main = $('main');
            main.draggable({
                drag: function (event, ui) {
                    
                    $(this).css({
                        'padding-right': Math.abs(ui.position.left),
                        'padding-bottom': Math.abs(ui.position.top),

                    });
                },
                scroll: false,
            });
        }
    }
    move.drag();
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden
  }

main {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background:url('https://previews.123rf.com/images/kitch/kitch1302/kitch130200221/18077895-an-illustative-grid-graph-pattern-or-background.jpg');
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

After a little more research I found out that I could also do this with background-position. So I'm using this as solution now. By dragging the green div.

```js
var move = {
        drag: function () {
            main = $('main');
            $('div').draggable({
                drag: function (event, ui) {
                    
                    main.css({
                         'background-position':ui.position.left + 'px ' +  ui.position.top + 'px',

                    });
                },
                scroll: false,
            });
        }
    }
    move.drag();
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden
  }

main {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background:url('https://previews.123rf.com/images/kitch/kitch1302/kitch130200221/18077895-an-illustative-grid-graph-pattern-or-background.jpg');
}
div {
  width:59px;
  height:59px;
  background:green;
  margin:124px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
      <div>
      </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

the below solution breaks a little bit the animation but did a contentious background .

your probleme is that the top and left are edited after drag finished so I tried to edit those by using timeout function ,

See below snippet:

```js
let newtop = newleft = 0;
let dataMain;
var move = {
  drag: function() {
    main = $('main');
    main.draggable({
      drag: function(event, ui) {

        newtop = Math.abs(ui.position.top);
        newleft = Math.abs(ui.position.left);
        
        $(this).css({
          'padding-right': newleft,
          'padding-bottom': newtop,
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
          main.css({
            'top':-newtop,
            'left':-newleft
          })
        },1);
      },
      scroll: false,
    });
  }
}
move.drag();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://previews.123rf.com/images/kitch/kitch1302/kitch130200221/18077895-an-illustative-grid-graph-pattern-or-background.jpg');
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>

  </main>
</body>
```